# Updating a table using subqueries

Tags: sql

A paticular artist: "Word" in my Artists table disbanded. Therefore I need to update the Members table. I suppose by NULL'ing out (nullifying?) the ID that paticular Artist was associated with.

My Artists Table looks like this:

### Artists

AritistID, ArtistName

### Members

MemberID, Lastname, Firstname

### XRefArtistsMembers

ArtistID, MemberID

I formulated the following query:

```
select a.artistid from artists a where exists
(select x.artistid from xrefartistsmembers x) in
(select m.memberid from members m);
```

Which produces an empty set. How can I nullify the field associated with that artistband: Word?

Comment: I would also prefer to use subqueries as I know that is faster processing.

Comment: I am using a Relational Database Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not a big fan of subqueries. You can easily join, but that is not the scope of the question.

It is pretty unclear what you are trying to do. I'm guessing that you are trying to delete an artist out of the Artist table, in which case you should delete the references too.

You could add a 'cascade on delete' behavoir on the foreign key 'ArtistID' in the XRefArtistsMembers table.

If you like to delete the record manually, you can do so by the following query..:

DELETE FROM XRefArtistsMembers WHERE ArtistID = (SELECT ArtistID FROM Artists WHERE ArtistName = 'Word')